# Using size_t for specifying the precision of a string in C's printf

Tags: c, c99

I have a structure to represent strings in memory looking like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t l;
    char   *s;
} str_t;
```

I believe using size_t makes sense for specifying the length of a char string. I'd also like to print this string using `printf("%.*s\n", str.l, str.s)`. However, the `*` precision expects an `int` argument, not `size_t`. I haven't been able to find anything relevant about this. Is there someway to use this structure correctly, without a cast to `int` in the `printf()` call?

Comment: are you not planning on null terminating the `char*`? If it's null terminated, I don't see what setting the precision to the length would get you in the first place. Beyond that, I think your choices are: cast or change your `size_t` to an `int` and just never allow it to be negative.

Comment: @EvanTeran The strings actually point to pieces within a larger buffer, so the `null` character is somewhere further. The size of an `int` is not a problem, as the strings are generally at most a few hundred bytes. What frustrates me is that even though `size_t` would fit this purpose nicely, C99 does not define a special precision modifier which accepts a `size_t` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a macro

```
#define STR2(STR) (int const){ (STR).l }, (char const*const){ (STR).s }
```

and then use this as `printf("%.*s\n", STR2(str))`.

Beware that this evaluates `STR` twice, so be carefull with side effects, but you probably knew that already.

**Edit:**

I am using compound initializers such that these are implicit conversions. If things go wrong there are more chances that the compiler will warn you than with an explicit cast.

E.g if `STR` has a field `.l` that is a pointer and you'd only put a cast to `int`, all compilers would happily convert that pointer to `int`. Similar for the `.s` field this really has to correspond to a `char*` or something compatible, otherwise you'd see a warning or error.

Comment: Still a cast, but it does look better than casting at every step. Just wondering, how exactly is that compound initializer different than an explicit cast? GCC's docs mention that: "Compound literals for scalar types and union types are also allowed, but then the compound literal is equivalent to a cast." (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

Comment: @LuciStanescu, no not a cast, as I said, an implicit conversion. All casts are conversions but not all conversions are casts. The difference would be if you'd pass in a `"STR"` that has a field `.l` that would be a pointer and not an integer type. If it'd be a cast all compilers would happily convert. For a conversion most compilers would warn you. BTW same is true for the `.s` field, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Indeed, although GCC's manual mentions that for scalar types the compound initializer is equivalent to cast, it does complain if a non-interger type is passed.

Comment: You don't need to cast size_t to int. On 64 arch. both int and size_t are passed to printf as 8-byte arguments

Comment: @user447503, just wrong. The problem arises just for 64 bit architectures. Usually they have 32 bit `int` and 64 bit `size_t`.

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int)str.l, str.s)
//               ^^^^^ use a type cast
```

**Edit**

OK, I didn't read the question properly.  You don't want to use a type cast, but I think, in this case: tough.

Either that or simply use fwrite

```
fwrite(str.s, str.l, 1, stdout);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: +1 for `fwrite` suggestion.  Although I would probably go with `fwrite(str.s, 1, str.l, stdout)` and check the return value to see how many characters were actually written successfully.

Comment: The example `printf()` call I gave was really just an example and the question clearly specifies that the goal is to use size_t to specify a precision. If you're wondering why I don't like the `fwrite` suggestion: once you start having more complex constant strings, multiple str_t strings, numbers and use `snprintf` for building a message, it gets too annoying not to use the formatting functions. So I believe I'm stuck with the "tough" suggestion from your answer :-). But cheers!

Comment: @nemo: I thought of that but you then have to deal with a short return count > 0 whereas with my version, the return value is either 1 (success) or 0 (failure).  According to the docs on `fwrite()` on my PC (Mac OS X), you only get a short count on a write error anyway, so you probably want to stop, no matter what at that point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the size_t is an int, or that it can be represented within an int.  It's just part of C's legacy in not defining the exact size of an int, coupled with concerns that size_t's implementation might need to be leveraged to address large memory areas (ones that have more than MAX_INT values in them).

The most common error concerning size_t is to assume that it is equivalent to unsigned int.  Such old bugs were common, and from personal experience it makes porting from a 32 bit to a 64 bit architecture a pain, as you need to undo this assumption.

At best, you can use a cast.  If you really want to get rid of the cast, you could alternatively discard the use of size_t.

Comment: Actually, there's a guarantee that `size_t` will never be equivalent to `int`; it might, though, be equivalent to `unsigned int`.  (It must be unsigned; its size might or might not be the same as the size of `int`.)